# Is there POS in Moqui?

Tags: moqui

I have explored and implemented erp using ofbiz.

Would like to switch to moqui for next project but I am unable find proper documentation.

Also I am not aware if moqui has a point of sale and web pos. Also e-commerce shows few products and cart, so do i need to develop further or i am missing something?

I have already referred links on [moqui.org](http://moqui.org/).

I would really appreciate if someone would poin out right direction with proper links.

Answer (score 1):

As of now there is no POS application based in the Moqui Ecosystem of open source projects, and to my knowledge there is not one in general based on Moqui Framework.

More generally the business level projects/components in the Moqui Ecosystem are more ERP oriented than ecommerce oriented, though PopCommerce has some ecommerce functionality and in the next release it will have much more (there is a lot of new ecommerce and retail/wholesale ERP functionality already in the source repository). There is also a component available for migrating data from OFBiz to the Mantle UDM data model which might be helpful (see https://github.com/jonesde/OFBizToMantle).

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt response. I really appreciate your help, Thanks a lot.